# issue while passing ajax header information

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, amazon-web-services

I am getting some issue while trying to run a client side javascript where I need to pass headers through ajax. While the same is working in php/curl , I am not getting why it is not working through ajax. After I a bit or search I found out how to pass headers in ajax. But still I am getting below issue.

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at
>   https://cej3j6och1.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/staging/accounts/login.
>   (Reason: missing token 'access-control-allow-headers' in CORS header
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' from CORS preflight channel).

I have alredy seen some posts here with this issue, but I think if my php/curl code is working , then js /ajax should also work. 
Below is the html single file which contains a button, on click of which, ajax call is there to post the information and get the response. I am sure there is some issue with the way I am passing the header information in ajax.

This is aws_login.html

```
<button onclick="login()">Login</button>
<div id="respData"></div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function login()
{
    var postData = {"email": "mgftest1507_p3@gmail.com",
                    "password":"TVRJeg",
                    "social_login":"no",
                    "provider":"",
                    "provider_id":""
                };
        var strData = JSON.stringify(postData);
        //alert(postData);
        alert(strData);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "text",
        beforeSend: function (request)
        {
            request.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", '*');
            request.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", 'OPTIONS');
            request.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", 'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token');
            request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", 'application/json');
            request.setRequestHeader("x-api-key", 'RmnZWntaBy42ZHkL9KoHY90KTIXfQVNY5TJsSAoA');
        },
        crossOrigin: true,
        crossDomain: true,
        url: "https://cej3j6och1.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/staging/accounts/login",
        headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods':'OPTIONS',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers':'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token',
        'Content-Type':'application/jsonp',
        'x-api-key':'RmnZWntaBy42ZHkL9KoHY90KTIXfQVNY5TJsSAoA',
        },
        data: strData,
        success: function(response, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
            alert(response);
            $('#respData').html(response);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

I have already tried ***beforeSend*** and ***headers*** separately in the function. Both didnt work. 
Below is php / curl code which runs absolutely fine.
This is aws_login_pc.php

```
<?php
    $url = 'https://cej3j6och1.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/staging/accounts/login';
    $client = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
    curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
                array('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token',
                'Content-Type: application/json',
                'x-api-key: RmnZWntaBy42ZHkL9KoHY90KTIXfQVNY5TJsSAoA',
              ));
  $arr = array(
  'email' => 'mgftest1507_p3@gmail.com',
   'password' => 'TVRJeg',
   'social_login' => 'no',
   'provider' => '',
   'provider_id' => ''
  );
  $array_val = json_encode($arr);
  curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $array_val);
  $head = curl_getinfo($client);
  $raw = curl_exec($client);
  $result = json_decode($raw);
  curl_close($client);

  echo '<pre/>';
  print_r($result);
  echo '</pre>';
  ?>
```

Both are single independent files. So anyone can try by running in their local. The html file can be run without any server also. I think I need to find a way by which I can send all those curl parameters in ajax also.

Comment: `if my php/curl code is working , then js /ajax should also work` - clearly you have `seen some posts here with this issue` - but seeing is not understanding, is it

Comment: remove the `access-control` headers you are sending in curl and stare in bewilderment as curl still works

Comment: @JaromandaX - I have removed and updated the question, still it is not working.  However  - madalin's answer is working.

Comment: Well how wonderful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `Access-Control` header and the `beforeSend` event

See the following:

```
 var postData = {
   "email": "mgftest1507_p3@gmail.com",
   "password": "TVRJeg",
   "social_login": "no",
   "provider": "",
   "provider_id": ""
 };
 var strData = JSON.stringify(postData);
 //alert(postData);
 alert(strData);
 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   dataType: "text",
   crossOrigin: true,
   crossDomain: true,
   url: "https://cej3j6och1.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/staging/accounts/login",
   headers: {
     'Content-Type': 'application/jsonp',
     'x-api-key': 'RmnZWntaBy42ZHkL9KoHY90KTIXfQVNY5TJsSAoA',
   },
   data: strData,
   success: function(response, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
     alert(response);
     $('#respData').html(response);
   }
 });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tL5rh8ds/